# Revert MinMax scaling

Tags: python, equation

I have an array of value (percentages) scaled from 0 to 100:

```
[34,  34,  84,  28,  56,  56,   0,   0, 100]
```

I know that these values have been scaled with a MinMax scaler:

```
V = (actual - min) / (max - min)
```

And then multiplied by 100 to have the percentages above. I didn't perform this transformation so I don't have actual, min, or max. But I have V.

I wanted to use `numpy.linalg.solve`, but I obviously can't express V as a linear/independent combination of actual, min, max.

Is it a known problem?

Comment: you have a system of n equations and n+2 unknowns, so I'm not sure you can reverse it.

Comment: Do I ? min and max are always the same in this array.

Comment: yes but do you have min/max values, if you have them then it's n equations n unknowns and it's pretty standard to solve using `actual = V(max-min)+min` otherwise, multiple solutions are possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can obtain the actual numbers back. Consider the following lists:

```
actuals1 = [34,  34,  84,  28,  56,  56,   0,   0, 100]
actuals2 = [3.4,  3.4,  8.4,  2.8,  5.6,  5.6,   0,   0, 10]
actuals3 = [340,  340,  840,  280,  560,  560,   0,   0, 1000]
actuals4 = [17,  17,  42,  14,  28,  28   0,   0, 50]
```

If you perform your MinMax scaling, you obtain same result with all of them so there is no unique result. That is because you obtain a parametric solution due to your undetermined system (as mentioned in Reda Drissi's comment), so any multiply of a solution is a valid solution.