# Revert MinMax scaling with 2 overlapping lists

Tags: python, numpy, equation

Following my question here: [Revert MinMax scaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000914/revert-minmax-scaling/56001205#56001205), I'm trying another approach.

This time, I have 2 big lists:

```
[ ...many values, 0, 20, 22, 32, 11, 24,  0, 12, 11, 33]
                [26, 25, 34, 45, 45, 35, 71, 27, 27, 34, many values...]
```

The values in the 2 big lists have been scaled with a MinMax scaler:

```
V = (actual - min) / (max - min)
```

min and max are constant within a list. min and max are different for the 2 big lists.

The two big lists "overlap" in two smaller lists:

```
[ 0, 20, 22, 32, 11, 24,  0, 12, 11, 33]
[26, 25, 34, 45, 45, 35, 71, 27, 27, 34]
```

For the first list, I know that:

```
V = (actual - min1) / (max1 - min1)
```

And for the second list, I know that:

```
 V = (actual - min2) / (max2 - min2)
```

So technically, I can express `actual` as a function of `min1, min2, max1, max2`,

```
V1.max1 - V1.min1 + min1 - V2.max2 +V2.min2 - min2 = 0
<=> V1.x0 - (V1+1).x1 - V2.x2 + (V2-1).x3 = 0
```

get a set of 4 equations, and solve with `numpy.linalg.solve`:

```
data = [(V1, V1+1, V2, V2-1) for V1, V2 in zip(vals1, vals2) if V1 !=0 and V2 != 0]
res = [0 for v in data]

x = np.linalg.solve(data, res)
```

But I get a `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` exception each time I try to do that:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    401     signature = 'DD->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'dd->d'
    402     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 403     r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    404
    405     return wrap(r.astype(result_t, copy=False))

lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     95
     96 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 97     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     98
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Am I missing independent equations again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the same V does not mean you have 2 equations for 2 variables, but 2 equations for 4 variables, this is still not resolvable unfortunately.

To resolve a system with n unknown variables, you need at least n independant equations.

A good thing is, you can "set" min1 and min2, and can deduce max1 and max2 (if for instance you know min1 will be always 0, or if you do not care of the actual min value)